# Plot Piecewise Function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I would like to plot the following piecewise function in Python using Matplotlib, from 0 to 5.

`f(x) = 1, x != 2; f(x) = 0, x = 2`

In Python...

```
def f(x):
 if(x == 2): return 0
 else: return 1
```

Using NumPy I create an array

```
x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

    array([ 0. ,  0.2,  0.4,  0.6,  0.8,  1. ,  1.2,  1.4,  1.6,  1.8,  2. ,
        2.2,  2.4,  2.6,  2.8,  3. ,  3.2,  3.4,  3.6,  3.8,  4. ,  4.2,
        4.4,  4.6,  4.8])
```

I have tried things like...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x,f(x))
```

Or...

```
vecfunc = np.vectorize(f)
result = vecfunc(t)
```

Or...

```
def piecewise(x):
 if x == 2: return 0
 else: return 1

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
plt.plot(x, map(piecewise, x))

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

But I am not using these functions correctly, and am now just randomly guessing how to do this.

Some answers are starting to get there... But the points are being connected into a line on the plot. How do we just plot the points?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Some answers are starting to get there... But the points are being
>   connected into a line on the plot. How do we just plot the points?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
 if(x == 2): return 0
 else: return 1

x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

y = []
for i in range(len(x)):
   y.append(f(x[i]))

print x
print y

plt.plot(x,y,c='red', ls='', ms=5, marker='.')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([-1, 2])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the function `f` does not take an array as input but a single numer. You can:

```
plt.plot(x, map(f, x))
```

The `map` function takes a function `f`, an array `x` and returns another array where the function `f` is applied to each element of the array.

Comment: Will update my post with the code I used, but I am getting, `ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension`

Comment: `plt.plot` needs an array or list, not a generator (which is what `map` returns), use : `plt.plot(x, list(map(piecewise, x)))`

Comment: Plots now... But the points are being connected by a line... how does one just plot the points?

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT You can use `plt.scatter` instead of `plt.plot` in order to plot just the points

Answer (score 4):

You can use [np.piecewise](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) on the array:

```
x = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x, np.piecewise(x, [x  == 2, x != 2], [0, 1]))
```

Comment: Trying to use this approach to visual solve a limit problem. Looking at this chart you would think the limit would be 0... And making 0.2 smaller results in a vertical line a x=2... Anyway to NOT connect the points of the line?

Comment: @DanCiborowski-MSFT, you choose whatever type of plot you want, if you want a scatter plot then use a scatter plot

Comment: This gives me the error [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x92bd828>]

Answer (score 1):

Your function is continuous except for an interval of zero measure. In my opinion the correct way to plot it is

```
In [8]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ...: plt.plot((0, 5), (1, 1), color='blue', label='Discontinuos function')
   ...: plt.scatter(2, 0, color='blue')
   ...: plt.grid()
   ...: plt.legend()
   ...: plt.show()

In [9]:
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the append works but requires a little extra processing. np's piecewise works fine. could just do this for any function:

`

```
import math
import matplotlib as plt

xs=[]
xs=[x/10 for x in range(-50,50)]   #counts in tenths from -5 to 5

plt.plot(xs,[f(x) for x in xs])
```

`

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 2.x, map() returns a list.
so you can write code as this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


def f(t):
    if t < 10:
        return 0;
    else:
        return t * t - 100;


t = np.arange(0, 50, 1)

plt.plot(t, map(f, t), 'b-')

plt.show()
```

if you are using python 3.x, map() returns a iterator.
so convert the map to a list.

```
plt.plot(t, list(map(f, t)), 'b-')
```