# Plotting piecewise contour graph in Python

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, plot, contour

I want to plot a piecewise function in Python where there are two variables `x` and `y`. This means I would need some kind of contour graph. In Matlab one may use

```
syms x y
eq1 = 0.1*(x/2)^2-0.3*(y/4)^2; 
eq2 = 0.15*(x/3)^2-0.25*(y/2)^2;

ezplot(eq1,[-5 5 -10 10]);
hold on
ezplot(eq2,[-4 4 -5 5]);
```

where `ezplot` plots `eq1 = 0` over `xmin < x < xmax` and `ymin < y < ymax`. Is there any (simple) equivalent function(s) in Python?

I have looked at the solutions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638508/plot-piecewise-function-in-python). Their problem only involves one variable `x` so it's not helpful in my case.

Comment: I don't see a piecewise definition of a function here, can you explain more precisely?

Comment: Sorry, I only wrote one "piece" of the piecewise function. (FYI this is just a MWE.) I've added another piece.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the different pieces by using `numpy`'s `masked array`.
At first define your functions, the x and y ranges and their 2D versions for the contour plot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.ma import masked_array as marr

def eq1(x, y):
    return 0.1*(x/2)**2-0.3*(y/4)**2
def eq2(x, y):
    return 0.15*(x/3)**2-0.25*(y/2)**2

x = np.linspace(-5, 5, 101)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 201)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

Now we need a 2D mask (or some, depending on the number of pieces of the piecewise function) to separate definition ranges of the different pieces of the function:

```
maskx = ((xx>=-4) * (xx<=4))
masky = ((yy>=-5) * (yy<=5))
mask = maskx * masky
```

This can be applied to different masked arrays:

```
res1 = marr(eq1(xx, yy), mask)
res2 = marr(eq2(xx, yy), ~mask)
```

Plotting a masked array leaves all the area blank where the mask is True:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)
axs[0].contour(xx, yy, res1)
axs[0].contour(xx, yy, res2)
axs[0].set_title('contour')
axs[1].contourf(xx, yy, res1)
axs[1].contourf(xx, yy, res2)
axs[1].set_title('contourf')
```

[image]